# How to keep the content of a ListView even after changing Fragment through the Drawer

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

I am using Android Studio and I created an Activity that contains a NavigationDrawerFragment.
One of the Fragments is loading the content of an SQLite database inside a ListView, using a custom ArrayAdapter with complex items.

My problem is that if I select another fragment in the drawer, then come back to this one, the onCreate() of the Fragment is called again, so is the onCreateView(), and the database is loaded once again.

How can I preserve everything without having to load the database nor populate the list again?

I don't have this problem when orientation changes, so I am a bit confused. Maybe it is because I have a layout for both Portrait and Landscape ?

here is the code of the onCreateView()

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActivity().getActionBar().show();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_papers, container, false);

        allItems = new ArrayList<ItemData>();

            getAllItemsFromDB("");


        mAdapter = new ItemsList(getActivity(), allItems, this, mDBApi);

        // Set the adapter

        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mListView.setOnScrollListener(this);

    return view;
}
```

and the getAllItemsFromDB() contains something like

```
public void getAllItemsFromDB(String query){

Cursor c = sqldb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM 'Table' " + query, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {

        allItems.add(parseSQL(sqldb, c));


    }

    c.close();

}
```

Comment: did you figure this out @Myoch

Answer (score 1):

Set your array list static

```
private static List<ItemData> allItems;
```

Then check it for null and initialise it only once

```
if(allItems == null) {
     allItems = new ArrayList<ItemData>();
     getAllItemsFromDB("");
}
```

Comment: is it ok to have it static if the content changes with user's actions?

Answer (score 0):

may be ur loading frament everytime as

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new UrFragment()).commit();
```

Don't do that, create instance of fragment and use it.

```
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new UrFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: I am already using the second option.
I have checked and the new Fragment() call is in the onCreateView() method of the NavigationDrawer. And this method is only called once at the start of the app.

Comment: Do not keep activities option is enabled in Settings -> Developer options.

Comment: what is Settings -> Developer options?